# splitting an html response using c++

Tags: c++, parsing, c++14

First of all, let me start by saying that i know about html parsers on github, but i dont want to include a parser for such a small task. Im trying to split this "value=" and the other end '">' to get whats inside of value="needthisvalue".

```
inline std::vector<std::string> split_given_string(const char*& string, char delimiter) {
    std::string part;
    std::stringstream split_string(string);
    std::vector<std::string> split_vector;
    std::cout << delimiter;
    while (std::getline(split_string, part, delimiter))
    {
        split_vector.push_back(part);
    }
    return split_vector;
}
```

This is my function to split a given string. It works with delimiters such as ":" but it doesnt work with other delimiters.

```
char first_delimiter[8] = "value=\"";
```

This is something like what i need as far as i know.

```
std::vector<std::string> split = split_given_string(html_c_string, first_delimiter[8]);
```

This is my call to the split function. When printing out the vector it just holds the original content that i fed into it. It doesnt actually split anything. The html is quite large but that shouldn't matter. This

Answer (score 1):

Your code is written for single-char delimiters, it won't work for multi-char delimiters.  You would need something more like this instead:

```cpp
inline std::vector<std::string> split_given_string(const std::string& str, const std::string& delimiter) {
    std::vector<std::string> split_vector;
    std::cout << delimiter;
    std::string::size_type start = 0, end;
    while ((end = str.find(delimiter, start)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        split_vector.push_back(str.substr(start, end-start));
        start = end + delimiter.size();
    }
    if (start < str.size())
    {
        split_vector.push_back(str.substr(start));
    }
    return split_vector;
}
```

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> split = split_given_string(html_c_string, "delimiter");
```

However, you are not wanting to look for 1 delimiter, you are wanting to look for 2 delimiters acting together, so I would suggest something more like this instead:

```cpp
inline std::vector<std::string> split_given_string(const std::string& str, const std::string& start_delimiter, const std::string& end_delimiter) {
    std::vector<std::string> split_vector;
    std::cout << start_delimiter << "..." << end_delimiter;
    std::string::size_type start = 0, end;
    while ((start = str.find(start_delimiter, start)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        start += start_delimiter.size();
        if ((end = str.find(end_delimiter, start)) == std::string::npos) {
            break;
        }
        split_vector.push_back(str.substr(start, end-start));
        start = end + end_delimiter.size();
    }
    return split_vector;
}
```

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> split = split_given_string(html_c_string, "value=\"", "\"");
```

Comment: yep, that helped me a lot, thank you for explaining why my implementation was not working and giving a fix.